# Binding a view model in ASP.NET MVC for contact form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I haven't been building ASP.NET MVC websites for very long, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with my view model? I'm trying to build a contact form for a website, however when I click "Submit" the form will completely ignore the JavaScript validation as well as the if (ModelState.IsValid) statement?!

I wasn't sure if it's because I'm not passing the model into my controller POST method?

I'd really appreciate if someone with more experience in ASP.NET MVC could take a look.

Thanks!

My view:

```
@model ThePines.ViewModels.EnquiryForm

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Enquiries", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <table cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8">
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "First Name")</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "medium" })</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, "Last Name")</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "medium" })</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "Email Address")</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { @class = "long" })</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, "Country")</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Country, new { @class = "medium" })</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartySize, "Party Size")</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PartySize, new SelectList(ViewBag.PartySizes), "Party Size")</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartySize)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArrivalDay, "Arrival Date")</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ArrivalDay, new SelectList(ViewBag.ArrivalDay), "Day") @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ArrivalMonth, new SelectList(ViewBag.ArrivalMonth), "Month") @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ArrivalYear, new SelectList(ViewBag.ArrivalYear), "Year")</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArrivalDay) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArrivalMonth) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArrivalYear)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartureDay, "Departure Date")</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartureDay, new SelectList(ViewBag.DepartureDay), "Day") @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartureMonth, new SelectList(ViewBag.DepartureMonth), "Month") @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartureYear, new SelectList(ViewBag.DepartureYear), "Year")</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartureDay) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartureMonth) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartureYear)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question, "Question")</td>
            <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Question, new { @rows = "5", @cols = "35" })</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Send Enquiry" style="padding: 5px 10px;" />
</fieldset>
}
```

My view model:

```
namespace ThePines.ViewModels
{
    public class EnquiryForm
    {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a first name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter an email address")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a valid email address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a party size")]
    public int PartySize { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter an arrival day")]
    public int ArrivalDay { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter an arrival month")]
    public int ArrivalMonth { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter an arrival year")]
    public int ArrivalYear { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a departure day")]
    public int DepartureDay { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a departure month")]
    public int DepartureMonth { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a departure year")]
    public int DepartureYear { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Please enter a question")]
    public string Question { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
using ThePines.ViewModels;

namespace ThePines.Controllers
{
public class EnquiriesController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Enquiries/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.PartySizes = Enumerable.Range(1, 8);
        ViewBag.ArrivalDay = Enumerable.Range(1, 31);
        ViewBag.ArrivalMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, 12);
        ViewBag.ArrivalYear = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 3);
        ViewBag.DepartureDay = Enumerable.Range(1, 31);
        ViewBag.DepartureMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, 12);
        ViewBag.DepartureYear = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 3);

        return View();
    }

    // POST: /Enquiries/

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection enquiryForm)
    {
        ViewBag.PartySizes = Enumerable.Range(1, 8);
        ViewBag.ArrivalDay = Enumerable.Range(1, 31);
        ViewBag.ArrivalMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, 12);
        ViewBag.ArrivalYear = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 3);
        ViewBag.DepartureDay = Enumerable.Range(1, 31);
        ViewBag.DepartureMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, 12);
        ViewBag.DepartureYear = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 3);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            message.Append("Name: " + enquiryForm["FirstName"] + " " + enquiryForm["LastName"] + "\n");
            message.Append("Email Address: " + enquiryForm["EmailAddress"] + "\n");
            message.Append("Country: " + enquiryForm["Country"] + "\n");
            message.Append("Party Size: " + enquiryForm["PartySize"] + "\n");
            message.Append("Arrival Date: " + enquiryForm["ArrivalDate"] + "/" + enquiryForm["ArrivalMonth"] + "/" + enquiryForm["ArrivalYear"] + "\n");
            message.Append("Departure Date: " + enquiryForm["DepartureDate"] + "/" + enquiryForm["DepartureMonth"] + "/" + enquiryForm["DepartureYear"] + "\n");
            message.Append("Questions: " + enquiryForm["Questions"]);

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendMailSmtp"]);

            mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendMailFrom"]);
            mail.To.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendMailTo"]);
            mail.Subject = "The Pines Enquiry";
            mail.ReplyToList.Add(enquiryForm["EmailAddress"]);
            mail.Body = message.ToString();

            smtpServer.Send(mail);
        }

        return View(enquiryForm);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have added parameter of action `FormCollection`, you need to pass `ViewModel` object so that it checks the Model State, currently you are posting FormCollection instead of `ViewModel` In your action, so your ViewModel is not posted, do like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(EnquiryForm enquiryForm)
    {
      if(ModelState.IsValid)
      {

        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        message.Append("Name: " + enquiryForm.FirstName + " " + enquiryForm.LastName + "\n");
        message.Append("Email Address: " + enquiryForm.EmailAddress + "\n");
        message.Append("Country: " + enquiryForm.Country + "\n");
        message.Append("Party Size: " + enquiryForm.PartySize + "\n");
        message.Append("Arrival Date: " + enquiryForm.ArrivalDate + "/" + enquiryForm.ArrivalMonth + "/" + enquiryForm.ArrivalYear + "\n");
        message.Append("Departure Date: " + enquiryForm.DepartureDate + "/" + enquiryForm.DepartureMonth + "/" + enquiryForm.DepartureYear + "\n");
        message.Append("Questions: " + enquiryForm.Questions);

       MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
       SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendMailSmtp"]);

        mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendMailFrom"]);
        mail.To.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendMailTo"]);
        mail.Subject = "The Pines Enquiry";
        mail.ReplyToList.Add(enquiryForm.EmailAddress);
        mail.Body = message.ToString();

        smtpServer.Send(mail);
    }

    return View(enquiryForm);

    }
```

Currently you are doing this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection enquiryForm)
    {

    }
```

or if you want to read posted data from `FormCollection` you can do like this in action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(EnquiryForm enquiryFormModel,FormCollection enquiryFormCollection)
        {

        }
```